# Vimeo API: Retrieving "End Screen" Video Settings Without an Attached Preset

Tags: vimeo, vimeo-api

I would like to know how to obtain the "End Screen" settings for a specific video that is not configured using a preset.

The `outro_*` fields do not appear in the `GET /videos/xxx` response.

Thanks!